# Does The new java synchronization mechanism preserve the code optimization by JVM.

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

as we know that synchronization method or synchronization  blocks preserve the java code and JVM does not optimize the code . is the this true for the new java synchronization mechanism.

Comment: What _new java synchronization mechanism_?

Comment: New Java synchronization mechanism? What are you talking about?

Comment: We don't know those things.  The JVM has always had some sort of optimization for synchronization, and for 1.7 (released in 2010) the optimization was pretty extensive.

Comment: All code is optimised whether synchronized or not.  Using sychronization prevents some optimisations e.g. code re-ordering, but these are fairly isolated examples.  Note: code inside a synchronized block can be re-ordered it is harder to move code from inside to outside a synchronized block, but even this can happen.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly: yes the java.util.concurrent primitives establish the same happens-after semantic than synchronized.

See ["Memory Consitency Properties"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#package_description) in the Package description.

Comment: BTW: "new" is pretty relative :) I think its more than 10 years now.